# Run two commands in discord.py at same time

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a small bot that downloads audio from a youtube video and uploads it to Anonfiles. Here is the code at that point:

```
@commands.command(name='audio')
async def audio_download(self, ctx, name, *, link: str):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = f'{cwd}/media/audio'
    
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'outtmpl': f'{path}/{name}.mp3',
        'quiet': True
    }

    abspath = f'{path}/{name}.mp3'

    with ytb.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([link])

    r = requests.post('https://api.anonymousfiles.io',
                    files={'file': open(f'{abspath}', 'rb')})

    json_all = json.loads(r.text)
    url_file = json_all["url"]

    await ctx.send(f'File: {url_file}')

    os.remove(abspath)
```

The problem is when two different people wanna download at the same time. When this code runs, the bot stop responding to any command until the task has ended, I mean, until the file is uploaded to the Anonfiles. Is there a way to make this code assyncronous and make two people can use it at the same time? The people **A** wanna download audio from video **X**, and the people **B** wanna download audio from video **Y**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using the thread libary like this:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

bot1_thread = Thread(target = bot1)
bot2_thread = Thread(target = bot1)
```